# "ui-packages" folder doesn't show up after successful import of figma component with Relay for Android Studio

Tags: android, figma

I'm using the guided tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/relay/convert-designs-android-studio) to convert the designs from Figma into code in Android Studio.

I encountered a problem at step 7, although I completed the previous steps successfully. Here's a brief summary of what I've done so far by following the guide:

1. Imported the HelloFigma component project into Figma and received a link to my component.
2. Added the "Relay For Android" plugin in Android Studio and included the plugin dependency in the gradle file.
3. Integrated a personal access token (PAT) into the Relay plugin for Android Studio.
4. Created the component in code according to the provided instructions.
5. However, I'm facing two issues:

- The "ui-packages" folder, which should be generated after clicking "create" in the Relay plugin, is not appearing.
- I encountered a build error when i launched a "build and refresh", as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Build error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugRelayCode'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.google.d2c.gradle.GenerateCode$GenerateCodeWorkAction
   > Converting SVG files: Exception Converting SVG resources for hello_card.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

What am i missing or doing wrong ?

I was expecting the "ui-packages" folder to be created and the build to be successful as to render the preview of my hellofigma component

Edit:
After locking my computer and being away from it for several hours, I returned and successfully resolved issue number 1.
Here are the steps I took to fix the problem:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Delete the "ui-packages" folder that was created in the file system, even though it didn't appear in Android Studio.
3. Repeat steps one to seven from the guide.
4. Now the "ui-packages" appear in Android Studio with the correct folders and files.

I still get error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugRelayCode'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.google.d2c.gradle.GenerateCode$GenerateCodeWorkAction
   > Converting SVG files: Exception Converting SVG resources for hello_card.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I hope this information is helpful to someone!